# How to tweak kubernetes.yml so that the livenessprobe only fail after five healthcheck failures

Tags: kubernetes

How to tweak kubernetes so that the liveness probe only fail after five health check failures

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add `failureThreshold: 5` option (idk what it's called correctly). k8s doc: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/#configure-probes